# Excluding a file extension while parsing a CSV file

Tags: regex, perl, csv

So I'm new to Perl and writing a script that would read through rows in a CSV file, and rename a directory of files associated with a certain column in that CSV file.

```
my $filename_formatted = "$row->[3]"."_"."$row->[4]"."_"."$row->[2]\n";
my $resume_id = $row->[1];


if (-e $resume_id){
    rename($resume_id, $filename_formatted);
}
```

Basically, how could I format `$resume_id` to accept only the contents up to the file extension? The `$row->[1]` variable contains something like "resume_1231.pdf" or "resume_1231.doc". I basically want everything up to the `.`

I understand I would probably need a regex, but, I've never utilized it in Perl.

`$formatted_resume_id = /($row->[1])?!\..*$/`

I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> The `$row->[1]` variable contains something like "resume_1231.pdf" or "resume_1231.doc".
>
> I basically want everything up to the `.`

Try with capturing group.

```
^([^.]*)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/mA2hI5/6)

OR using Lazy way.

```
^(.*?)\.
```

Sample code:

```
$mystring = "resume_1231.pdf";
if($mystring =~ m/^([^.]*)/) {
    print "The file name is $1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would want everything up to the final dot in the file name (so you would get the full name even if the filename contained dots).

Something like this should do it:

```
if ( $row->[1] =~ /(.*)\./ ) {
    $formatted_resume_id = $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was apparently this,

```
my $resume_file = "bogus_filename.doc";

 my ($name) = $resume_file =~ /(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)/;

 my($ext) =  $resume_file =~  /(\.[^.]+)$/;
```

This would account for any extra periods, as it only accepts up to the very last period.

I'm still a bit unsure as to how this works, so if anyone can break down the first regex, that would be  great. I understand (.+?) but I'm lost as to how the second part of that regex means to not include the extension.